# Reduce Javascript File Size or Split? Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-serve

I am testing out my production build and I am getting this warning

```
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (3.65 MiB)
      main.css
      main.js
```

What can I do to make it small or should I be splitting it up into smaller chunks?

If so how?

Here is what I got for my webpacks

webpack.prod

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  // Provides process.env.NODE_ENV with value production.
  // Enables FlagDependencyUsagePlugin, FlagIncludedChunksPlugin,
  // ModuleConcatenationPlugin, NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, OccurrenceOrderPlugin,
  // SideEffectsFlagPlugin and UglifyJsPlugin.
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  // see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/
  optimization: {
    // minimize default is true
    minimizer: [
      // Optimize/minimize CSS assets.
      // Solves extract-text-webpack-plugin CSS duplication problem
      // By default it uses cssnano but a custom CSS processor can be specified
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        // only use MiniCssExtractPlugin in production and without style-loader
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Mini CSS Extract plugin extracts CSS into separate files.
    // It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS.
    // It supports On-Demand-Loading of CSS and SourceMaps.
    // It requires webpack 4 to work.
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
});
```

webpack.common

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    // filename and path are required
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // JSX and JS are all .js
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ]
};
```

By using the BundleAnalyzerPlugin I was able to shave about 1mb by just importing the fonts I need from Font Awesome and by ignoring all the moment locals.

I still think it can be smaller.

Comment: remove unused libraries/code ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - I am not really sure how to find out which packages are which sizes also I don't know how much that will actually bringing it down.  So looking for alternatives as well.

Comment: So may be at the beginning put content of `package.json` file here

Answer (score 0):

minify your javascript and css files (just search for javascript/css minifier), there are many libraries online that will allow you to do this, just make sure to have a backup of the source files beforehand.

Comment: I think the setup of my webpack already does it. I added my config.